# How to get specific value from chained json in javascript whit mapQuest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, mapquest

I ppl, im trying to get lat and lng from MapQuest Decoding Json... but my javascript is so bad that i dont know if im supossed to use jquery or not, maybe whit parse i simply can...

Im sending an Address to the Json to calculate Lat and Lng...

```html
<input type="hidden" id="address" value=" @(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
                                                              this.Model.Calle, this.Model.Altura,
                                                              this.Model.localidadesInmueble.nombre,
                                                              this.Model.provinciasInmueble.nombre)) " />
                <output id='map' style="width:700px; height:525px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
```

Here mi Javascript Code:

```js
<script>
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {

        var JsonMapQuest = JSON.parse('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&location=Address');
        //var JsonMapQuestDecoded = decodeURI($JsonMapQuest);
        
        var lat1 = $jsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lat;
        var lon1 = $jsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lng;
        // Posicion del mapa
        var pos = { lat: lat1, lng: lon1 };
        // El mapa, centrado en la posicion
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 8, center: pos });
        // El marcador, posicionado en la posicion
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos, map: map });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

This is the JSON that I get from url...

```html
{
  "info": {
    "statuscode": 0,
    "copyright": {
      "text": "© 2018 MapQuest, Inc.",
      "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
      "imageAltText": "© 2018 MapQuest, Inc."
    },
    "messages": []
  },
  "options": {
    "maxResults": -1,
    "thumbMaps": true,
    "ignoreLatLngInput": false
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "providedLocation": {
        "location": "Washington,DC"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "street": "",
          "adminArea6": "",
          "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood",
          "adminArea5": "Washington",
          "adminArea5Type": "City",
          "adminArea4": "District of Columbia",
          "adminArea4Type": "County",
          "adminArea3": "DC",
          "adminArea3Type": "State",
          "adminArea1": "US",
          "adminArea1Type": "Country",
          "postalCode": "",
          "geocodeQualityCode": "A5XAX",
          "geocodeQuality": "CITY",
          "dragPoint": false,
          "sideOfStreet": "N",
          "linkId": "282772166",
          "unknownInput": "",
          "type": "s",
          "latLng": {
            "lat": 38.892062,
            "lng": -77.019912
          },
          "displayLatLng": {
            "lat": 38.892062,
            "lng": -77.019912
          },
          "mapUrl": "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=KEY&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,38.892062,-77.019912,0,0,|&center=38.892062,-77.019912&zoom=12&rand=306744981"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is not working, there are no map in my page.. The result must have, a map generated whit google maps, whit center and marker on the Address that i have put on the url that mapQuest gave to me...

Comment: Please ask a clear question.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to get Lat and Long from the Json that MapQuest gives to me, sending Address as a parameter, get the values, and then, fill the var pos to send to google maps and get the location of Address

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  Does it error? Is it not working?  Please update the question with more information.  What is happening and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You are using the Mapquest geocoding service to display information on a Google map. If you don't have a paid Business Enhanced or Business Plus Enhanced plan with Mapquest, this would be a violation of their [Terms of Service](https://developer.mapquest.com/legal). (Search the page for "geocoding".) Geocoding is an expensive service to provide, so the service providers tend to be fussy about wanting to get paid for it. You might consider consolidating both services with one provider, but watch out for either one's ToS and pricing!

Comment: On the technical side, one important thing for you to do right now is learn how to use the developer tools in your browser. These will show you many of your errors and help you debug them. Here is a [guide to the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools). I suggest going through the entire guide and trying everything it suggests. You will learn a lot about JavaScript and about how to debug your code.

Comment: Already edit the post to answer your questions, does not show any map, thats the problem... the map was working only whit google maps, puting some lat and lng random... now that i add the geocode whit MapQuest i dont get anything

Comment: Thanks! i was debbuging whit f12 and ctrl+shift+j... but the messages of error are complex to me, I though that if it was a sintax mistake i can solve from you help from here, but debbug is the solution ever ! thanks!

Comment: both services, Maps from Google, and Geocode from MapQuest are paid... i didnt know that i cant use them in the same method,... ApiGeocode from google is too much expensive than MapQuests..

Comment: Oh, please forgive me for making the wrong assumption! Here is the part of the Mapquest ToS that got me worried: "Unless Extended Rights Geocoding license is included in Customer’s monthly subscription with MapQuest, Customer may only use Standard Rights Geocodes (i.e., may only use Geocodes in conjunction with a MapQuest Map). Customer may not use the grant of Extended Rights Geocodes unless Customer has either signed up for the Business Enhanced or Business Plus Enhanced plans." But if you have paid accounts of the appropriate type on both services, then you can definitely use them together.

Comment: No problem!!! now maps are working ok, but i think the problem is sending my "address" inside the json chain...

Answer (score 0):

`JsonMapQuest` and `$jsonMapQuest` obviously is not the same thing ...

You'll have to decide how to call it and then stick with it, for example:

```
var JsonMapQuest = ...
var lat = JsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lat;
var lng = JsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng.lng;
```

Likely this would also work, which is a few lines less, because it skips all that useless processing:

```
var position = JsonMapQuest.results.locations.latLng;
```

Comment: Try JsonMapQuest.results.locations[0].latLng.lat.